# Shopping Cart Price Rule - Discounts on Products when buying as combo

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, cart-rule

I have 5 products say 'PROD1' to 'PROD5'. If the customer buy any other products along with any one of these 5 products, I want to give a discount. Is this possible to configure.

Answer (score 0):

Set the condition to contain one of your spacial products and, at the same time, some other product. See the image:
[image: shopping-cart-rule-amasty]